# <tr> tag not recognized using php for loop

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, tags, tr

I have this code to make a 2 week calendar and I've used a for loop to write the dates. The first for loop is for this week and the second is for next week. I have the for loops inside < tr > tags because I want each week in a different row.

```
<tr>
<?php
   for($i=$start1; $i <=$end1; i++){
      echo "<td><a href='#' class='tablelink'>".$i."</a></td>";
   }
?>
</tr>
<tr>
<?php
   for($i=$start2; $i <=$end2; i++){
      echo "<td><a href='#' class='tablelink'>".$i."</a></td>";
   }
?>
</tr>
```

However, when I view it in my browser, all the dates are on the same line. Both for loops are being put in the first < tr > tag and the second < tr > tag is empty.

```
<tr>
<td><a href="#" class="tablelink">13</a></td>
<td><a href="#" class="tablelink">14</a></td>
...etc
<td><a href="#" class="tablelink">26</a></td>
</tr>
<tr></tr>
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: This does not look like an error. Rather, it looks like `$start2` is greater than `$end2`

Comment: I don't understand, $start2 is 20 and $end2 is 26

Comment: Hi
Each row in a table will have the same number of columns.Then it will work.

Comment: They should both have 7 columns, instead the first has 14 and the second has 0 and I don't know why.

Comment: @ArielleLePage, if you think your variables are correct, why don't you just echo them before you run those two loops?

Answer (score 0):

I think in your code:

$end1 = $start2 = 26 and $end2 < 26

So, double check the values of $end1 , $start2 and $end2

Comment: oh I see. Thanks. 
Do you know how I would adjust for weeks that the month changes?

Comment: Set: $end1 = 13 , $start2 = 14 and $end2 = 26